# BlueBream framework and multi connections to databases

Tags: python, zope3

I put the first steps in [BlueBream framework](http://bluebream.zope.org/). In my project I must get data from RDBMS - MySQL, PostgreSQL and MS Server. For now, I made a simple tutorial helloworld :) I know how to write Interfaces and Implementations, etc.

My question is: How to set up a connections to RDBMS and multiple connections?  Could you give me a simple "step by step" tutorial ?

How to bake a database? Is in BlueBream something like a  command  "syncdb" in Django?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [zope.sqlalchemy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.sqlalchemy); it integrates [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) into the Zope transaction manager. SQLAlchemy in turn lets you access many different databases, including MySQL, PostgreSQL and MS Server.

The zope.sqlalchemy package explains how to obtain a SQLAlchemy session. From there on out you use bog-standard SQLAlchemy operations for which there are plenty of tutorials and help here on SO. SQLAlchemy can also take care of setting up the database schema for you, if that is needed.